# Google Map Marker OnClick event

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am using Googe Map API V2 and android to make an android application. Here is the code where I put my marker:

```
private void addBusStopMarker(){
    final Intent intent1;
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(1.28213,103.81721)).title("10009 - Bt Merah Ctrl").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.busstopicon)).snippet("Average Commuters: 9,940"));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(1.28294,103.82166)).title("10089 - Jln Bt Merah - B08").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.busstopicon)).snippet("Average Commuters: 2,050"));
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
             if(arg0.getTitle().equals("10009 - Bt Merah Ctrl"))
                 intent1 = new Intent(context, PopulationCharts.class);
                 startActivity(intent1);       
            return true;
        }
    });    
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is when the marker is selected, it will shows the info window which is from the code above. Then when I select the snippet, it will execute the onMarkerClick event.

However, from the code above, it shows me an error message: `The final local variable intent1 cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`. Also, I not sure how to set marker snipper onClick event
.
Thanks in advance.

**Edited portion**

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(context ,PopulationCharts.class);
           startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

**Error Message**

```
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemap/com.example.googlemap.PopulationCharts}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at com.example.googlemap.PopulationCharts.<init>(PopulationCharts.java:28)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)
07-29 12:24:12.774: E/AndroidRuntime(15704):    ... 11 more
07-29 12:24:20.563: I/Process(15704): Sending signal. PID: 15704 SIG: 9
```

**Population class**

```
package com.example.googlemap;

public class PopulationCharts extends Activity{

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String markerTitle= intent.getExtras().getString("markertitle");

    //Pie chart 
    private GraphicalView chartPop;
    private String[] ageGroupPop;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.population_charts);
        openChartAgeGroupPop();
        openChartPeakPop();
    }

    private void openChartAgeGroupPop(){     
        //codes to generate pie chart
    }

    //Line chart
    private View lineChart;
    private String[] time = new String[] {
            "0700", "0800" , "0900", "1000", "1100", "1200", "1300", "1400", "1500", "1600", "1700", "1800"};

    public void openChartPeakPop(){
        //code to generate multiple line chart
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you click the info window you will start an activity??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `OnInfoWindowClickListener` so when you click the marker it will show first the `Infowindow` and when the window is click it will then start the activity

**sample:**

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
       Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, PopulationCharts.class);
       String title = marker.getTitle();
       intent1.putExtra("markertitle", title);
       startActivity(intent1);  
    }
});
```

to get the value in PopulationCharts activity class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String markerTitle= intent.getExtras().getString("markertitle");
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the marker title and pass it to another class when the info window is onClick?

Comment: @20Cents see edit above, and use the marker parameter to get the title of the marker

Comment: But it giving me NullPointerException error message. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @20Cents show the error and which part of code is it/

Comment: Let me post the error message. Can you please help me check?

Comment: @20Cents what is line PopulationCharts.java:28

Comment: It's the two lines you posted to get the value in PopulationCharts activity class

Comment: @20Cents can you post your whole PopulationCharts class

Comment: @20Cents put the 2 line of code that I did inside your oncreate after setContentview() method

Comment: Thanks, it works! But could you please explain to me why is it so? Is it because the code does not execute when onCreate?

Comment: @20Cents You are still waiting for the intent to be initialized but you put it when you created your activity does resulting to null. And puting it in the onCreate is to make sure that Intent is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event **setOnInfoWindowClickListener** the syntax is that:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){           
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
          if(marker.getTitle().equals("10009 - Bt Merah Ctrl")){
            Intent info = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
            startActivity(info);
          }
        }
    });
```